# making an image show up in pygame

Tags: python, image, pygame

I'm trying to make a game with pygame and I want to make an image appear when I click, but I do not know how to program that function.

```
import pygame, sys, time, os
pygame.init()
windowImg = pygame.display.setmode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Videogame 001")
clock = pygame.tima.Clock()

landerImg = Pygame.image.load("C:\RedSquare.jpg")
landerX = 200
landerY= 200
while True:
    clock.tick(15)
    for event in pygame.even.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT
         pygame.display.quit()
         sys.exit()
if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        pygame.draw(landerImg)
#this is the part of the code where i do not know ho to make an image appear when I click
        pygame.display.flip()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pygame, sys, time, os
pygame.init()
windowImg = pygame.display.set_mode((800,600))
pygame.display.set_caption("Videogame 001")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

landerImg = pygame.image.load("C:\\RedSquare.jpg")
landerX = 200
landerY= 200
while True:
    clock.tick(15)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
         if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
             pygame.display.quit()
             sys.exit()

         if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
             #this is the solution to your problem
             windowImg.blit(landerImg,(landerX ,landerY))
             #######################

    pygame.display.flip()
```